# What is the difference between AmbientServices and CompositionContext in Kephas?

Tags: dependency-injection, kephas

From what I noticed, they do pretty much the same thing, provide services in form of IoC/DI. However, `IAmbientServices` has a member of type `ICompositionContext`. I don't really get the difference between the two of them and why are they aggregated this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concise answer is: the `ambient services` contain services registered *before* the IoC/DI/composition container is built, while the `composition context` is the root container for the IoC/DI, and itself is a service registered into the `ambient services`.

As a side note, all the services registered in the `ambient services` are later registered automatically also in the DI container, including `IAmbientServices`, so they are available for composition, too.

Examples for ambient services:

- *log manager*: provider of loggers.
- *type loader*: loads types from assemblies.
- *configuration store*: provides primary configuration settings.

As a general rule of thumb, prefer using services registered in the DI container, you will need very rarely ambient services.

Comment: Is there a reason to use a container like AmbientServices instead of simply using some kind of static variables? I mean such ambient services must be only a few.

Comment: There are more reasons to use ```IAmbientServices``` instead of static variables: 1. leverage unit testing; 2. provide a central registry for application root services, even if they are not so many; 3. available through composition, direct use is typically not recommended; 4. besides being a service registry, is also an expando object, can be extended dynamically at runtime; 5. ```AmbientServices.Instance``` is of type ```IAmbientServices``` and can be set upon bootstrapping, so you are in full control what is behind it :).